# How to catch exception from ReactiveCommand?

Tags: c#, exception, task, reactiveui

I know how to handle exceptions thrown by async tasks called by `ReactiveCommand<T>` but how do I handle an exception that is thrown before the task is returned?

In the following example `ThrowAndHandle` command will throw an exception from the async task when executed and the exception will be handled. The command `ThrowButFailToHandle` demonstrates that I can not use `ThrownExceptions` to handle an exception that does not occurr "in" the task but rather before the task is created. How can such an exception be handled?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IReactiveCommand ThrowAndHandle { get; private set; }
    public IReactiveCommand ThrowButFailToHandle { get; private set; }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        ThrowAndHandle = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => ThrowFromTask());
        ThrowAndHandle.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(HandleException);

        ThrowButFailToHandle = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => ThrowBeforeTaskIsReturned());
        ThrowButFailToHandle.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(ThisMethodWillNotBeCalled);
    }

    private Task ThrowFromTask()
    {
        return Task.Run(() => 
        {
            throw new Exception("This exception will appear in IReactiveCommand.ThrownExceptions");
        });
    }

    private Task ThrowBeforeTaskIsReturned()
    {
        throw new Exception("How can I handle this exception?");
    }

    private void HandleException(Exception ex)
    {
        // This method is called when ThrownFromTask() is called
    }

    private void ThisMethodWillNotBeCalled(Exception ex)
    {   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your commands are directly bound to UI, the short answer is you can't.

The exception will be propagated to the onError handler of `ExecuteAsync` observable, which is ignored as per the implementation of `Execute`:

```
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteAsync(parameter).Catch(Observable.Empty<T>()).Subscribe();
    }
```

Now if you deeply need to catch this exception, you can certainly:

- wrap the ReactiveCommand into an ICommand, with a different `Execute` behavior upon error
- wrap the lambda passed to `CreateAsyncCommand` to return a failure task result upon exception
- issue/PR on reactiveui to propagate these exceptions also to `ThrownExceptions`